# Is there a matlab like editor for javascript?

Tags: javascript, editor

I'm a matlab programmer and started to work with javascript. I wanted to know if there is any tool (editor) for programming in JavaScript that is like the matlab frontend? 
This features are just great in matlab:

- syntax check
- code analysis on the fly
- integrated console
- debugging (set stop points, step by step, etc...)

Is there something similar for JavaScript?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try :

- [Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/)
- [Visual Studio Express 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products)
- [Comparison of JavaScript-based source code editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors)

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like Aptana, along with js lint for assisted editing and checking. For JavaScript, the debugger is the browser. Chrome developer tools or firebug for Firefox have all those capabilities.

Comment: Internet Explorer 9 and up also have great debuggers